# Get focus textarea id after click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to obtain textarea id which was focused when i clicked another element.

I use `$(':input:focus').attr('id')`, but after click textarea looses focus immideatly and I cann't obtain id of textarea was selected.

Could somebody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `.focusout()` method:

```
$('#focusedItem').focusout(function() {
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
});
```

Comment: Thanks! But the problem is that this way I get id of last focused textarea. I mean that it would be great get nothing if when i clicked no textarea was selected.

Comment: so if nothing will be focused, the focusout() event wont even fire :)

Comment: No, i mean, if i focus textarea, after go to the text for example and in global variable i hold id of last focused textarea. And when i click on the button, for example, I cannot different: was curet in textarea at click or not.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can hold the id in a global variable to obtained it and one checked that currently which input type is focused.

Like it:

```
var areaId = $('textarea:focus').attr('id');
```

Either use above code or use below code:

```
var areaId = "";
//define this variable at the top of starting the javascript code.
areaId = $(':input:focus').attr('id');
```

Or you can use the [`focusout()`](http://api.jquery.com/focusout/) function of jQUery:

```
$(':input').focusout(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
});
```